# How to show const variable name in disassemble'd code in gdb?

Tags: gcc, gdb, llvm-clang

I have the following code which is compiled with -g option.

```
$ cat main.c 
/* vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2: */
#include <stdio.h>

int U_var;
int I_var=42;
const int C_var=2;

static void inc_U_var() {
    U_var+=C_var;
}

void inc_I_var() {
    I_var+=C_var;
}

int main() {
    inc_U_var();
    inc_I_var();
    return 0;
}
```

In gdb, the constant C_var is shown as `$2`. Is there a way to preserve the const variable name in the disassembly code? Thanks.

```
(gdb) disassemble inc_I_var
Dump of assembler code for function inc_I_var:
   0x0000000100000ec0 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000100000ec1 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000100000ec4 <+4>: mov    0x156(%rip),%eax        # 0x100001020 <I_var>
   0x0000000100000eca <+10>:    add    $0x2,%eax
   0x0000000100000ecd <+13>:    mov    %eax,0x14d(%rip)        # 0x100001020 <I_var>
   0x0000000100000ed3 <+19>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000100000ed4 <+20>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) list inc_I_var
7   
8   static void inc_U_var() {
9       U_var+=C_var;
10  }
11  
12  void inc_I_var() {
13      I_var+=C_var;
14  }
15  
16  int main() {
```

Comment: As I know there is no a simple way to do it.  GDB can show you only names of variables which stored in a memory, not in registers. Look like radare2 have the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> How to show const variable name in disassemble'd code in gdb?

You cannot : at compile time the `const int C_vars` is replaced by its value, so in the assembler you have `$2` rather than an access to `C_var`, gdb has no way to know where 2 comes from

Comment: for the guy voting down without any explication : say why please